# Meaning of "totes" in "totes can be used for personal items"

Tags: word-meaning

[Source](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/daily-life-coping/shared-housing/index.html):

> Sinks could be an infection source and should avoid placing toothbrushes directly on counter surfaces. **Totes** can be used for personal items so they do not touch the bathroom countertop.

Does this tote stand for "a plastic box" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tote#Noun))?

I also thought of "tote bag", but that would not be very handy, would it, to put bags on the countertop? So I thought that a small plastic container would be ideal. But on the other hand, the Wiktionary article says that the container meaning refers to logistics.

Comment: That seemed like an odd use of "totes" to me. A tote bag is much larger than I would use for toiletries. Typically I would use a smaller [toiletry bag](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=+toiletry+bag&t=ffnt&atb=v112-1&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images). After looking around though, I found that there are [shower totes](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22shower+tote%22&t=ffnt&atb=v112-1&ia=images&iax=images) and they seem like something designed for college students sharing a common bathroom.

Comment: @ColleenV - thank you! It must be "shower totes" indeed, judging by Google Pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From the same dictionary definition, a tote is a "tote bag", a large bag with handles.
The plastic box definition has to do with "logistics", that is, with shipping of goods.